# Visual Studio 2013 new project templates appear empty

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013, and when opening a new project the templates appear to be empty[image]

I also get this error:

[image]

I have tried re-install with no success. How is it possible to fix this error?

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime.

Comment: Did you have any other visual studio version installed before installing 2013

Comment: no, only Microsoft Visual Studio Tools 2010 for Office Runtime.

Comment: Clear your MEF cache: Delete the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache` directory and restart VS.

Comment: And possibly the template caches too: delete `ItemTemplatesCache` and `ProjectTemplatesCache` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE`.

Answer (score 0):

I have un install Visual Studio 2013, and install Visual Studio 2012, problem solved.